# Converting string column to multiple binary columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

| row_num | ref | value | sub_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ref1 | value1 | sub1 |
| 2 | ref1 | value1 | sub2 |
| 1 | ref2 | value1 | sub2 |
| 2 | ref2 | value2 | sub1 |
| 3 | ref2 | value2 | sub3 |
| 4 | ref2 | value4 | sub1 |
| 1 | ref2 | value1 | sub2 |
| 2 | ref2 | value2 | sub1 |

Ultimately I want to be able to query something like:
**select unique refs that have value1 AND value2 OR sub1**

I thought the best way to do it would be to convert the table into a different format more like this:

| unique_ref | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | sub1 | sub2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ref1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

but I don't know how to go about setting this up.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  What does the OR refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using conditional aggregation.  It is a little unclear what you want, but for (value1 and (value2 or sub1)) this would look like:

```
select ref
from t
group by ref
having countif(value = 'value1') > 0 and
       countif(value = 'value2' or sub_value = 'sub1') > 0;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. is there an easy way to concat the fields, so it can be like SELECT ref, CONCAT(values....)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and there are multiple ways to approach this problem and can be achieved based on the data types of columns `value` & `sub_value`.

If you are not interested in the count and with just `value` & `sub_value` occurrence and if it's of STRING type, I would go alternatively with `STRING_AGG` & `REGEXP_CONTAINS` (will try to manipulate the regex-based)

```
SELECT
  ref,
  value_agg,
  sub_agg
FROM (
  SELECT
    ref,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT value) value_agg,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT sub_val) sub_agg
  FROM
    table_data
  GROUP BY
    ref )
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(value_agg, '^.*value1.*$')
  AND (REGEXP_CONTAINS(value_agg, '^.*value2.*$')
    OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(sub_agg, '^.*sub1.*$'))
```